# Behaviour of a certain $L$ function at $s=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

I was going through [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2003-16-01/S0894-0347-02-00410-1/) paper. Corollary 7.3.4 says the $L$-function $L(s,\pi, \rm{sym}^4)$ is holomorphic except possibly at $s=0,1$ and gives a necessary and sufficient condition for it to have a pole at $s=1$ where $\pi$ is a cuspidal representation of $\rm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$.

But it does not talk about the behaviour of the fucntion at $s=0$. Can we give a necessary and sufficient condition for the function to have a pole at $s=0$?

Also if $\pi$ is not monomial then, $L(s,\pi, \rm{sym}^4)$ does not have a pole at $s=1$. Can we say more? Can we say it is non-zero or zero at $s=1$?

Similarly, by corollary 5.1.7, $L(s,\rm{sym}^2(\pi)\otimes \chi)$ does not have a pole at s=1 iff $\pi$ is not monomial. Can it have a zero there or is it always non-zero at $s=1$ when $\pi$ is not monomial?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you say what $\pi$ is to make your question self-contained?

Comment: @Kimball $\pi$ is a cuspidal representation of $\rm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $n\geq 1$.  The $L$-function of an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ is either (1) entire, or (2) holomorphic away from a pole of order $\leq n$ at $s=1+i\tau$ for some fixed $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$.  Kim (Theorem B) proved that if $\pi$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(2)$, then $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^4)$ is the $L$-function of an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(5)$.  Therefore, there is no pole on the line $\mathrm{Re}(s)=0$.

The automorphy of $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^4)$ follows from the automorphy of the exterior square lift from $\mathrm{GL}(4)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(6)$.  The cuspidality criterion for this exterior square lift prove [here](https:///math.okstate.edu/people/asgari/Files/cuspidality.pdf) directly determines the order of the pole at $s=1+i\tau$ of $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^4)$.

If $\pi$ is an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, then $L(1+it,\pi)\neq 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  See the appendix to [this paper](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Ebrumley/Research_files/HC-Schwartz.pdf) for a much stronger zero-free region.

With some modifications, all of these comments (holomorphic apart from possible pole at $s=1+i\tau$, classification of factorization that determines the order of the pole at $s=1+i\tau$, zero-free region that includes the line $\mathrm{Re}(s)=1$) apply to $L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^2(\pi)\otimes\chi)$.  The cuspidality criterion follows from seminal work of Gelbart and Jacquet.

Comment: The pole can be anywhere on $\Re(s)=1$, even when the central character is unitary. This is because $L(s,\pi\otimes|\det|^{it})=L(s+it,\pi)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Good point.  I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @2734364041 Thank you so much for the reply. It has helped me a lot. I have few doubts which I want to clear. I did not understand how to find the order of the pole of $L(s,\pi, \rm{Sym}^4)$ at $s=1$ from the paper of Raghuram-Shahidi? Also what is the order of the pole of $L(s, \rm{Sym}^2(\pi)\otimes \chi)$ at $s=1$?

Comment: @Kiddo For $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^4)$, the order depends on $\pi$. Let $F=\otimes_v F_v$ be an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(4)$. If the $F_v$'s satisfy the hypotheses of Theorem A in Kim's paper, then the exterior square lift $\Lambda^2 F$ is an automorphic representation fo $\mathrm{GL}(6)$. If $\omega$ is the central character of $\pi$, then $L(s,\Lambda^2(\mathrm{Sym}^3\pi)\otimes\omega^{-1}) = L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^4)L(s,\omega)$.  Raghuram-Shahidi tells you how the LHS factors. Similar game for $L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^2\pi\otimes\chi)$ using Gelbart-Jacquet.

Comment: @Kiddo (This is all in the intro to Kim's paper, by the way.)

Comment: @2734364041 I understood almost everything. I also got to know that $L(s, \rm{sym}^2 \otimes \chi)$ has a simple pole iff $\pi$ is monomial. But still I did not get how to know the order of the pole of $L(s, \pi, \rm{sym}^4)$. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Kiddo Whether or not $L(s,Sym^2\pi\otimes\chi)$ has a pole depends on BOTH $\pi$ and $\chi$, not just $\pi$.  If you know the poles of $L(s,\Lambda^2(Sym^4\pi)\otimes\omega^{-1})$, then you can determine the poles of $L(s,\Lambda^2(Sym^4\pi)\otimes\omega^{-1}) / L(s,\omega)$, which equals $L(s,Sym^4\pi)$.

Comment: @2734364041 Thank you.